# Why for loop in java wont make any difference if its present or not

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

In my program in certain function i have to fill 3x3 square of 9x9 array. At first glance it seems to be as trivial as it sounds but somehow one for() loop is not working properly. I asked two friends of mine and checked the code several times but still cant find any mistake everything seems to be working just fine if we do not count one for function. I tried to change it to other loop and it also didnt work. Below i give you my code and the outcome.I tried to serch the web for similar problem but also couldnt find one. Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ttabela
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean bylo[] = new boolean[10];
        int tabela[][] = new int[9][9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                tabela[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        wypelnianiePrzekatnych(bylo, tabela,0,2);
        clear(bylo);
        System.out.println("");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(tabela[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for(int x=0;x<9;x++)
            System.out.print(tabela[0][x]+" ");
    }
    static int RandomBeetween ( int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int a1 = random.nextInt(max - min);
        int a2 = a1 + min;
        return a2;
    }
        static void wypelnianiePrzekatnych(boolean[] bylo, int[][] tabela,int i,int j){//i=0 j=2

            int  a = i,b=i ;

            for (;a < (j+1);a++) { //This one doesnt make any difference
                for (;b < (j+1); b++) {
                    System.out.println("p "+a+" "+b+" k");

                    tabela[a][b] = RandomBeetween(1, 10);
                    System.out.println(tabela[a][b]);
                    if (bylo[tabela[a][b]] == true) {
                        do {
                            tabela[a][b] = RandomBeetween(1, 10);

                        }while (bylo[tabela[a][b]] == true);
                        bylo[tabela[a][b]] = true;
                        System.out.println(tabela[a][b]);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (bylo[tabela[a][b]] == false)
                            bylo[tabela[a][b]] = true;
                        System.out.println(tabela[a][b]);


                    }

                }
            }
        }
        static void clear(boolean[] bylo)
        {
            for(int h=0;h<10;h++)
                bylo[h]=false;
        }
        /*public static void wypelnianieReszty()
            {

            }*/
    }
```

Outcome:

```
p 0 0 k
7
7
p 0 1 k
8
8
p 0 2 k
3
3

7 8 3 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 

7 8 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: and, why do you assume a for loop has no impact?

Comment: becouse as we can see from outcome only 2nd loop does work and also i removed it and outcome was this same

Comment: Just a tip for future debugging. If you have a situation like this, the problem isn't always where it appears to be. Having a simple print line inside each for loop will often help you identify what's really going on. In this example, you'd notice that the outer for loop is doing exactly what it should but the inner loop is only running once.

Comment: @JustanormalguyII just because the result is the same, doesn't mean it didn't execute.

Comment: @Stultuske You are correct Sir thank you for advice

Comment: @Reece Coombes I tried that but then it started to be very messy and unreadable especially when some loops in my program are reapeting itself not specified number of times and outcome screen capacity is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your inner for loop will only execute once, so the outer loop has nothing to run after the first iteration.

I'll explain in more detail.

You start with:

```
 int  a = i,b=i ;
```

Let's say we passed in (..., 0, 2) as you have done. So `a = 0, b = 0`.

The outer for loop will run just fine exactly as expected - the code will run until `a > (j+1)` and there's nothing wrong here.

The problem is actually with your second for loop:

```
for (;b < (j+1); b++) {
```

For the first iteration, this will run as expected. But any time after that, it will never run - because you have already incremented b, such that `b == (j+1)`.

I believe there is a fairly simple solution, assuming I've interpreted your requirements correctly:

```
int  a = i;
int b;

for (;a < (j+1);a++) { //This one doesnt make any difference
    b = i
    for (;b < (j+1); b++) {
```

This works because it resets the value of b before each iteration of the for loop, so it won't halt immediately.

I hope this helps! Feel free to ask any questions in the comments.